# Reading multiple files

Tags: c++, ifstream

I want to alternate between reading multiple files. Below is a simplified version of my code.

```
ifstream* In_file1 = new ifstream("a.dat",  ios::binary);
ifstream* In_file2 = new ifstream("b..dat",  ios::binary);
ifstream* In_file;
int ID;

In_file = In_file1; 
int ID = 0;

//LOOPING PORTION
if (In_file -> eof())
{
  In_file -> seekg(0, ios_base::beg);
  In_file->close();

  switch (ID)
   {
     case 0:
           In_file = In_file2;  ID = 1; break;
     case 1:
          In_file = In_file1; ID = 0;  break;
   }
}
//some codes
:
:
In_file->read (data, sizeof(double));

//LOOPING PORTION
```

The code works well if I am reading the files one time and I thought that everything was cool. However, if the part termed 'looping portion' is within a loop, then the behaviour becomes weird and I start having a single repeating output. Please, can someone tell me what is wrong and how I can fix it? If you have a better method of tacking the problem, please suggest. I appreciate it.

//SOLVED

Thank you everybody for your comments, I appreciate it. Here is what I simple did:

Instead of the original

```
switch (ID)
{
  case 0:
   In_file = In_file2;  ID = 1; break;
   case 1:
   In_file = In_file1; ID = 0;  break;
}
```

I simply did

```
switch (ID)
{
  case 0:
   In_file = new ifstream("a.dat",  ios::binary);  ID = 1; break;
  case 1:
  In_file = new ifstream("b.dat",  ios::binary);  ID = 0;  break;
}
```

Now it works like charm and I can loop as much as I want:-). I appreciate your comments, great to know big brother still helps.

Comment: What happens when both are at EOF?

Comment: Shouldn't you be checking InFile->eof(), after assigning InFile?

Comment: `if the part termed 'looping portion' is within a loop` .. for example?

Comment: The idea is that when the EOF is reached, the next file is read from. I omitted where I reset the pointer. I will include it.

Answer (score 5):

Let's see: the code you posted works fine, and you want us to tell you
what's wrong with the code you didn't post.  That's rather difficult.

Still, the code you posted probably doesn't work correctly either.
`std::istream::eof` can only be used reliably after an input (or some
other operation) has failed; in the code you've posted, it will almost
certainly be false, regardless.

In addition: there's no need to dynamically allocate `ifstream`; in
fact, there are almost no cases where dynamic allocation of `ifstream`
is appropriate.  And you don't check that the opens have succeeded.

If you want to read two files, one after the other, the simplest way is
to use two loops, one after the other (calling a common function for
processing the data).  If for some reason that's not appropriate, I'd
use a custom streambuf, which takes a list of filenames in the
constructor, and advances to the next whenever it reaches end of file on
one, only returning `EOF` when it has reached the end of all of the
files.  (The only complication in doing this is what to do if one of the
`open`s fails.  I do this often enough that it's part of my tool kit,
and I use a callback to handle failure.  For a one time use, however,
you can just hard code in whatever is appropriate.)

As a quick example:

```
//  We define our own streambuf, deriving from std::streambuf
//  (All istream and ostream delegate to a streambuf for the
//  actual data transfer; we'll use an instance of this to
//  initialize the istream we're going to read from.)
class MultiFileInputStreambuf : public std::streambuf
{
    //  The list of files we will process
    std::vector<std::string> m_filenames;
    //  And our current position in the list (actually
    //  one past the current position, since we increment
    //  it when we open the file).
    std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator m_current;

    //  Rather than create a new filebuf for each file, we'll
    //  reuse this one, closing any previously open file, and
    //  opening a new file, as needed.
    std::filebuf m_streambuf;

protected:
    //  This is part of the protocol for streambuf.  The base
    //  class will call this function anytime it needs to
    //  get a character, and there aren't any in the buffer.
    //  This function can set up a buffer, if it wants, but
    //  in this case, the buffering is handled by the filebuf,
    //  so it's likely not worth the bother.  (But this depends
    //  on the cost of virtual functions---without a buffer,
    //  each character read will require a virtual function call
    //  to get here.
    //
    //  The protocol is to return the next character, or EOF if
    //  there isn't one.
    virtual int underflow()
    {
        //  Get one character from the current streambuf.
        int result = m_streambuf.sgetc();
        //  As long as 1) the current streambuf is at end of file,
        //  and 2) there are more files to read, open the next file
        //  and try to get a character from it.
        while ( result == EOF && m_current != m_filenames.eof() ) {
            m_streambuf.close();
            m_streambuf.open( m_current->c_str(), std::ios::in );
            if ( !m_streambuf.is_open() )
                //  Error handling here...
            ++ m_current;
            result = m_streambuf.sgetc();
        }
        //  We've either gotten a character from the (now) current
        //  streambuf, or there are no more files, and we'll return
        //  the EOF from our last attempt at reading.
        return result;
    }

public:
    //  Use a template and two iterators to initialize the list
    //  of files from any STL sequence whose elements can be
    //  implicitly converted to std::string.
    template<typename ForwardIterator>
    MultiFileInputStreambuf(ForwardIterator begin, ForwardIterator end)
        : m_filenames(begin, end)
        , m_current(m_filenames.begin())
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: @James Kanze: +1. Your answer provides a better approach than mine trying to fit logic in OP's code.

Comment: A vote for your answer. However, as a newbie, I have problem understanding the code and will take more time to study it. However I have a couple of questions. 1. Is it possible for the files to be used mulitple times? 2. Could you add a few comments to the code pls, to aid my understanding. I appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks for the accolades, but I'd like to stress my first suggestion: just use two loops.  Or one loop, in a function that is called twice.  It's the preferred solution unless you're doing this a lot; I developed `MultiFileInputStreambuf` initially to handle the Unix filter program conventions: my version also recognizes `"-"`, and reads from standard in if it sees it, and inserts a `"-"` if the sequence is empty, so `"argv + 1, argv + argc"` are valid arguments.

Comment: Hi, I have read from many source that dynamically allocating memory isn't a good idea, however, I have 9 files and 8 different variables to read. Now if I don't make exchange file names dynamically, you can imagine how much lines of code and untidy the code will appear. That is why somehow, your code seems fine because it is not monstrous. However, as I said, frankly, I wouldn't know how to use it yet.

Comment: @Deadie 1. Once you reach end of file on a file, you can't read any more without seeking.  You can open the same file several times, and read it each time. 2.  I'd be glad to add comments, but I'm not sure where you need them.  It's using one technique that isn't as widely known as it should be---defining new `streambuf`, and it makes what I would consider natural use of the standard library iterators---again, something that C++ programmers should be familiar with, but often aren't if they come from other languages.  I'll see what comments I can add.

Comment: @Deadie One comment about what you did.  Instead of constantly allocating new `ifstream` (and hopefully deleting them somewhere), you can use a single `ifstream`, calling `close` and `open` on it as I did on the `filebuf` in my example.  (No dynamic allocations means no overlooked `delete`s, no memory leaks, and in this case, no leaks of open file descriptors either.)

Comment: :-) @James thanks for the advice. Believe me, I have never delete dynamically allocated memory :-(. I should visit here often.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#define NO_OF_FILES 2

int main () 
{
  std::ifstream in;
  std::string line;
  std::string files[NO_OF_FILES] = 
  {
    "file1.txt", 
    "file2.txt",
  };
  // start our engine!
  for (int i = 0; i < NO_OF_FILES; i++)
  {
    in.open(files[i].c_str(), std::fstream::in);
    if (in.is_open())
    {
      std::cout << "reading... " << files[i] << endl;
      while (in.good())
      {
        getline(in, line);
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
      }
      in.close();
      std::cout << "SUCCESS" << std::endl;
    }
    else
      std::cout << "Error: unable to open " + files[i] << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```